# Update UHD Library Instead of USRP device firmware

Tags: gnuradio, usrp

I am trying to run lab tests on USRP using GNURadio from my own computer. When I run my code, I get an error that the USRP firmware is not compatible with my host code. I know that I can fix this by updating the USRP firmware; however, I cannot do this because the device is being used by other people in the lab using their own computers (which means it would require them to update their code build version on their own computers). Therefore, is there a way I can keep the USRP firmware untouched but update the UHD code in my GNURadio software instead?

Answer (score 1):

> Therefore, is there a way I can keep the USRP firmware untouched but update the UHD code in my GNURadio software instead?

Yes, you can do that, but it can be non-trivial to find a UHD version that matches your device's firmware. Also, obviously, it's always recommendable to use the latest version of UHD – Ettus strives to improve features and remove bugs with every version!

Note that after installing a different version of UHD, you **must** rebuild all software that links against UHD – which means that you **must** uninstall GNU Radio, and **must not** install it from your distibution's package repositories, but from source.